# Way to drag listview items till middle when reached bottom

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listitem, pull

Maybe a really vague description but basically exactly what I want.

When you reach the bottom of a listview the list stops with scrolling, you can't go further. 
What I want is that you can scroll further and that the bottom items scroll till the middle of the screen.
I tryed several things, but can't manage to find a way to do this.

Its just pull for refresh , but then from the bottom of, and it should not go back to refresh, but just stay there.

Hope my description helps, can't make it more clear, all help is really valued.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Add "blank" items at the end of the list.

Option 2: on the listview's XML add the following:

```
android:paddingBottom="80dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Option 3: programatically:

```
listView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 80);
listView.setClipToPadding(false);
```

Comment: Very nice, thnx! Is there also a solution which doesn't make this 'hack' noticeble for the user? as it leaves a big gap which you can see due the scrollbar as it leaves a space where you can't come with the scrollbar which doesn't look very well,